# how to compare an array element of a jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am having a difficult finding out how I can extract the value of an *element* of an *array* in a *jsonb* column and make a comparison.

In other words, I am trying to find out if `proto_nexthop` (is a key in a jsonb column that holds a list of IP addresses) IP address belongs to the subnet `84.116.198.0/23`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM vpn.route_targets 
WHERE is_ok=true 
  AND country='INTERNATIONAL' 
  AND INET ANY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements(pulse -> 'proto_nexthop'))::TEXT << INET '84.116.198.0/23' ;
```

Could you advise please what I am doing wrong and how to accomplish that ?

Example records:

```
# SELECT route_targets.value, pulse -> 'proto_nexthop' FROM vpn.route_targets WHERE is_ok=true AND country='INTERNATIONAL'  LIMIT 3 ;
     value      |                                                  ?column?                                                  
----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0101:933365229 | ["84.116.198.x"]
 0101:933365141 | ["84.116.x.x", "84.116.x.x", "84.116.x.x", "84.116.x.x", "84.116.x.x", "84.116.x.x"]
 0101:933365016 | ["84.116.x.x", "84.116.x.x"]
(3 rows)
```

Desired output:

```
     value      |                                                  ?column?                                                  
----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0101:933365229 | ["84.116.198.x"]
```

Comment: You should show sample rows from your tables with the  JSON  column and what output you are expecting to see.

Comment: thanks @KaushikNayak, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the elements from the array and then use that in an EXISTS operator:

```
SELECT rt.value, rt.pulse -> 'proto_nexthop' 
FROM route_targets rt
WHERE is_ok
  AND country='INTERNATIONAL' 
  AND exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements_text(rt.pulse -> 'proto_nexthop') as x(ip)
              where x.ip::inet << INET '84.116.198.0/23')
```

Comment: @onedreamcloser: that's a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)